# Return information about oldest employee in department, if department has more than 20 employees

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

Don't judge me, I'm new to SQL querying. I got scheme, like the one shown on picture below. So, there are 2 tables, first one Employees contains EmployeeID, FirstName, LastName, DateOfBirth and DepartmentID. The second one is called Department and contains DepartmentID and DepartmentName .

[image]

I want to return FirstName, LastName and DepartmentName for the oldest employee from each department containing more than 20 employees.

My solution is the following query :

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName, DepartmentName
FROM employees
LEFT JOIN department
ON employees.DepartmentID = department.DepartmentID
    WHERE (employees.DateOfBirth = 
(SELECT MIN(employees.DateOfBirth ) FROM (
SELECT *FROM employees WHERE employees.DepartmentID IN ( 
SELECT employees.DepartmentID FROM employees GROUP BY DepartmentID HAVING COUNT(*) > 20)));
```

I think that logic is fine, because inner `SELECT` statement will return ID's of every department with more than 20 employees, and the outer should return to oldest employee.

The problem that I have is when I try to execute this query, it is returning `SQL error` every derived table must have it's own alias.
I've tried putting alias on each derived table, but outcome is still the same.
Please, help me with this one.

Also, if someone has different solution, please share it.

Thank You.
Addition which strawberry asked for, `Create` queries

```
CREATE TABLE Employees
(
EmployeeID int, 
FirstName varchar(10),
LastName varchar(15),
DateOfBirth date,
DeparmentID int
)

CREATE TABLE Department
(
DepartmentID int, 
DepartmentName varchar(15)
)
```

Comment: Wow, an age discrimination query - a first on SO

Comment: If a derived table requires an alias, give it an alias! It's that simple. That said, this is one ugly query.

Comment: Time to eat lunch - comment deleted

Comment: Because MIN() will return the oldest date of birth

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper CREATE and INSERT statements (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: Sorry for saying that but it's not well performed query you can write this in more better ways, though you can try by replacing this line in your query HAVING COUNT(*) > 20)) t));

Comment: Your query is missing some closing brackets.

Answer (score 3):

Your query is tricky to read due to inconsistent formatting. So I'll clean it up as follows:

```
SELECT  FirstName, LastName, DepartmentName
FROM    employees
        LEFT JOIN department
        ON employees.DepartmentID = department.DepartmentID
WHERE   (employees.DateOfBirth = 
        (
        SELECT  MIN(employees.DateOfBirth)
        FROM    (
                SELECT  *
                FROM    employees
                WHERE   employees.DepartmentID IN (
                        --Departments with more than 20 employees
                        SELECT  employees.DepartmentID
                        FROM    employees
                        GROUP BY DepartmentID
                        HAVING COUNT(*) > 20)
                ) -- You need an alias here.
                  -- Also from this point you were missing closing brackets.
```

Problems with your query:

- Obviously the missing alias and closing brackets meant you couldn't even test your query.
- Also `SELECT MIN(employees.DateOfBirth)` returns only a single value. Not a value per department.
- So your overall result includes only the oldest employee across all the 'big' departments. (Unless the oldest employee in each department happened to have the same birth date.)
- It could also include results from a smaller department if any employee happened to have the same birth date the oldest from the big departments. And that employee needn't even be the oldest in their department!
- You also have some inefficiencies by using more sub-queries than necessary.

CTEs (common table expressions) are great at simplifying complex queries. But I don't know if mysql supports them. So this solution still uses sub-queries.

```
SELECT  e.FirstName, e.LastName, d.DepartmentName
FROM    employees e -- I prefer short aliases
        INNER JOIN (
        -- This sub-query returns the earliest birth date within each
        -- big department. This needs to be an aliased query so you
        -- can join to other tables for your desired columns.
        SELECT  DepartmentID, MIN(DateOfBirth) AS MinDOB -- Must alias column
        FROM    employees
        WHERE   DepartmentID IN (
                -- Big departments
                SELECT  DepartmentID
                FROM    employees
                GROUP BY DepartmentID
                HAVING COUNT(*) > 20
                )
        GROUP BY DepartmentID
        ) ddob -- Alias Department Date of Birth
        -- As a result of inner joining to ddob your employees
        -- will be filtered to only those that match the relevant
        -- ones identified in the query.
        ON  e.DepartmentID = ddob.DepartmentID
        AND e.DateOfBirth = ddob.MinDOB
        INNER JOIN Department d
        ON  d.DepartmentID = e.DepartmentID
```

Something to note in the above solution, if 2 employees are tied for being oldest in a department, both will be returned.

This approach is structurally similar to yours, but you could also approach the problem from another direction.

- Start out getting oldest employees in ALL departments.
- And only at the end filter the result according to department size.

I'll leave that to you to try. I suspect the query would be a little simpler.

Answer (score 0):

The following SQL script correspond to your Class Diagram:

```
CREATE TABLE Departments (
 DepartmentID int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
 DepartmentName varchar(15)
);

CREATE TABLE Employees (
 EmployeeID int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
 FirstName varchar(10),
 LastName varchar(15),
 DateOfBirth date,
 DepartmentID int,
 FOREIGN KEY (DepartmentID) REFERENCES Departments(DepartmentID)
);
```

Following your classes diagram, there is a department for each employee. So, is the reason of using `INNER JOIN`. I think the following query do what you want:

```
SELECT ee.FirstName, ee.LastName, ee.DateOfBirth, t.DepartmentName 
FROM
( 
     SELECT e.DepartmentID, d.DepartmentName, MIN(e.DateOfBirth) AS DateOfBirth 
     FROM Employees AS e
     INNER JOIN Departments AS d ON e.DepartmentID = d.DepartmentID
     WHERE e.DepartmentID IN (
         SELECT DepartmentID 
         FROM Employees 
         GROUP BY DepartmentID HAVING COUNT(DepartmentID) > 20
     )
     GROUP BY e.DepartmentID
) AS t
INNER JOIN Employees AS ee
WHERE ee.DepartmentID = t.DepartmentID AND ee.DateOfBirth = t.DateOfBirth
```

Example of output:

```
FirstName   LastName    DateOfBirth DepartmentName
fisrt14     last14      02/01/2000  SI
fisrt31     last31      12/01/2003  Finance
```

You improve its performance!

Comment: Your answer in incorrect. The condition `AND e.DateOfBirth = (SELECT MIN(DateOfBirth) from Employees);` means you'll at most return an employee who is the oldest in the entire company. I.e. you won't return oldest in a department unless he's also oldest across all departments.